# Finding the homogeneous part of general solution to second order non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I was given this non-homogeneous second order differential equation:

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + y = sec(x)$

In order to solve this, I need to find the **general solution to the homogeneous part** by finding the **characteristic equation** which is:

$\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$

$\lambda^2 = -1 $

$\lambda = \pm i $

According to my understanding, based on the **roots** from **characteristic equation** , the general solution to **homogeneous part** should be

$y_{homogeneous} = Ae^{ix} + Be^{-ix}$

But Instead,In my text, it was written as this:

$y_{homogeneous} = Acos(x) + Bsin(x)$

I am aware that I could use Euler's formula to convert my exponential terms into sine and cosine but even then I would not be able to get the solution given in the text.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. Like you said, why don't you use Euler's formula to turn your exponentials into sines and cosines and then *collect like terms*, remembering that

(A+B)

and

(A-B)i

are just constants, so can be replaced with another letter of your choosing.

Comment: I see, the A and B from my exponential form is not the same A and B on the given answer. I would prefer to use the exponential form to calculate the non-homogeneous part of the solution. Thanks for the help.